# Compiling Assimp.NET under Mono/Linux

Tags: .net, mono, pinvoke, dynamic-linking, assimp

I'm trying to use [MasterQ32's OpenWorld.Engine](https://github.com/MasterQ32/OpenWorld.Engine) on Ubuntu. I've followed the example scene from the "[Documentation](https://github.com/MasterQ32/OpenWorld.Engine/blob/master/Documentation/index.htm)". Everything is working well, except asset importing. Interestingly enough, the same error occurs on Windows 7 too: Assimp.NET's library loader can't find `kernel32.dll`. Below is the stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: kernel32
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Assimp.Unmanaged.NativeMethods:LoadLibrary (string)
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibraryImplementation.LoadLibrary (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary (System.String libPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary (System.String lib32Path, System.String lib64Path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadIfNotLoaded () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.EnableVerboseLogging (Boolean enable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.AssimpImporter.PrepareImport () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.AssimpImporter.ImportFileFromStream (System.IO.Stream stream, PostProcessSteps postProcessFlags, System.String formatHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenWorld.Engine.Model.Load (OpenWorld.Engine.AssetLoadContext context, System.IO.Stream stream, System.String extensionHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenWorld.Engine.Asset+<Load>c__AnonStorey0`1[OpenWorld.Engine.Model].<>m__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenWorld.Engine.Game.DeferRoutines () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: kernel32
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Assimp.Unmanaged.NativeMethods:LoadLibrary (string)
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibraryImplementation.LoadLibrary (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary (System.String libPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary (System.String lib32Path, System.String lib64Path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadLibrary () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.LoadIfNotLoaded () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.Unmanaged.AssimpLibrary.EnableVerboseLogging (Boolean enable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.AssimpImporter.PrepareImport () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Assimp.AssimpImporter.ImportFileFromStream (System.IO.Stream stream, PostProcessSteps postProcessFlags, System.String formatHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenWorld.Engine.Model.Load (OpenWorld.Engine.AssetLoadContext context, System.IO.Stream stream, System.String extensionHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenWorld.Engine.Asset+<Load>c__AnonStorey0`1[OpenWorld.Engine.Model].<>m__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenWorld.Engine.Game.DeferRoutines () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And here is the code I'm using, basically identical to the one in the [Doc](https://github.com/MasterQ32/OpenWorld.Engine/blob/master/Documentation/index.htm): Sets up a scene with a camera and a single object. I'm using the assets provided in the repository, and I verified that the asset path are correct.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using OpenWorld.Engine;
using System.Drawing;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenWorld.Engine.SceneManagement;
using OpenTK;

namespace OpenWorldLearn {

    public class TestGame : Game {
        Scene scene;
        PerspectiveLookAtCamera camera;

        protected override PresentationParameters GetPresentationParameters() {
            var def = base.GetPresentationParameters();
            def.GraphicsMode = new GraphicsMode(24, 24, 0, 0);
            def.Resolution = new Size(800, 600); 
            def.IsFullscreen = false;
            def.Title = "Potato!";
            return def;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad() {
            FrameBuffer.ClearColor = OpenWorld.Engine.Color.CornflowerBlue;

            Assets.Sources.Add(new FileSystemAssetSource("../../../Assets"));

            camera = new PerspectiveLookAtCamera();
            camera.FieldOfView = 90;
            camera.LookAt(new Vector3(-0.1f, 1.9f, -4f), Vector3.Zero);

            scene = new Scene();

            SceneNode child = new SceneNode();
            var renderer = child.Components.Add<Renderer>();
            renderer.Model = Assets.Load<Model>("crate");
            scene.Root.Children.Add(child);
        }

        protected override void OnUpdate(GameTime time) {
            scene.Update(time);
        }

        protected override void OnDrawPostState(GameTime time) {
            FrameBuffer.Clear();
            scene.Draw(this.camera, time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly this wont work on Linux.... I also very much doubt it does not work on Windows 7.

Comment: Well, at least with Xamarin Studio for Windows, I get the same results. (I'll never download a 7GB IDE, would take a month on my connection)

Comment: Assimp.NET only uses 3 functions from kernel32 (libc provides similar functionality too). But given it will try load a dll, it still wont work on non-Windows. I suggest you look for a non-Windows port of that library.

Comment: BTW, I think Mono might be buggy given the library is referred to without an extension. Again, not sure why such a silly bug would exist.

Comment: Well now you gave me a idea: the OW.E repository comes with a precompiled Assimp.NET library, I should probably get the source and recompile again under Mono, also fixing the extensions as you suggest.

Comment: I was just going to say that. Look on https://code.google.com/p/assimp-net/ It seems it does have Linux support now :D

Comment: Great! Apparently I'll also have to fix OW.E, since it seems a lot of names changed since that version.

Comment: Will be a good exercise. Perhaps you can send a pull request to OW.E for the update :p (if  you can get it working on both Windows/Linux)

Comment: Be sure I'll do, if I manage so!

Comment: **Status update:** Compiling Assimp.NET is causing trouble, even the updated version is causing trouble to run on Linux. (didn't try Windows yet, as my main goal is getting it on Linux) It seems the `.so` files are missing, and I have no idea on how to generate them (I suppose compiling the C++ Assimp? But I never used C++, so I have no idea yet).

Answer (score 1):

I think I've worked out what's going on - it's looking for a file called `Assimp32.so` / `Assimp64.so` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by P/Invoking `dlopen` but this will always return `IntPtr.Zero` because it's really called `libassimp.so` and is found at `/usr/lib/libassimp.so` if you install the `libassimp-dev` on 32-bit ubuntu 14.04. (NB have you installed assimp native headers for your platform?)

Also if it were me I would refactor this to trust the CLR to do `dlopen`/`dlsym`/`dlclose` by itself with standard P/Invoke rather than handrolling this with direct pinvokes into operating system APIs. You would then effectively replace the const function names in `AssimpFunctionNames` with extern methods decorated with `DllImportAttribute`. OTOH the one place I can think of that legitimately does this is [DarkJava](https://github.com/mooso/DarkNotes), where the function names are really not known at compile time.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the very late response. I downloaded the latest AssimpNet source and modified the code so it looks for `/usr/lib/libassimp.so` correctly, now there's a new issue: Assimp is trying to call unimplemented methods from `Assimp.InternalInterop`. (In fact, the whole class is not implemented) Here's the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/wXhtwezC.

Comment: Does [this]( https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=ROboVILrGoS-PJj3gPAB&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086294/convert-array-of-structs-to-intptr&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEkkE3c1usHaeR4yv1M5yFwrMSHXw&sig2=T1a_k9qLLfGng2RYUbox_w) help? marshal already has methods for putting primitives into native arrays. But ask a new question....