# Marshalling Array of Struct from IntPtr - Only First Value Marshals Correctly

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm passing an address to an array of structures into a C# DLL from an external program.

I thought that I would first make a simple test, in order to see if the approach would work, by trying to marshal a pointer into an array of structs on the C# side.

Given the following struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct TestStruct
{
    public int id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string someString;
}
```

and the following code which attempts to read the struct array (the section up until the for loop is just to simulate the pointer being passed from the other program):

```
TestStruct[] testStructs = new TestStruct[3];
testStructs[0].id = 1;
testStructs[0].someString = "Value 1";
testStructs[1].id = 2;
testStructs[1].someString = "Value 2";
testStructs[2].id = 3;
testStructs[2].someString = "Value 3";

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(testStructs[0]);
IntPtr ptrFirst = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(testStructs[0], ptrFirst, true);

long ptrAddrLong = ptrFirst.ToInt64();

for (int i = 0; i < testStructs.Length; i++) {
    IntPtr thisPtr = new IntPtr(ptrAddrLong);
    TestStruct testStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<TestStruct>(thisPtr);
    ptrAddrLong += size;
}
```

can anyone shed any light why, when I debug through the for loop, only the first testStruct item is marshalled correctly from the pointer? All subsequent items contain garbage in the fields, as it appears the pointer address is incorrect after the first iteration.

First iteration:
[image]

Second iteration:
[image]

Size is reported as 36, which seems to be correct.

I've tried using explicit layout, but this didn't make any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think that [Marshal.StructureToPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx) marshals anything more than you have told it to marshal?

`Marshal.StructureToPtr(testStructs[0], ptrFirst, true);` marshals a **single** TestStruct to the memory at `ptrFirst`.

It is basically just a smart memory copy that takes into account all those marshaling attributes.

**P.S.:** And take into account that memory at `ptrFirst` can hold at most `Marshal.SizeOf(testStructs[0])`. So you can't (at least without risking some [nasty memory access problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)) read a memory behind `ptrFirst + size`.

Comment: The first section of the code, before the for loop, was intended to simulate receiving a pointer from the other program. I thought it would be possible to increment the pointer value inside the for loop, marshaling the pointer address into a structure, to iteratively access each element of the array. If this is not the correct approach, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I'm not actually getting a pointer to the existing array am I, I'm marshalling a fresh, single TestStruct to a new piece of memory, which explains why the subsequent values are garbage.

Comment: @Hoodlum But in real code you have some IntPtr that points to an actual array of `TestStruct`s, am I correct? Also, if you want to create such IntPtr for demonstration you can look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086294/convert-array-of-structs-to-intptr

Comment: So basically sequentially marshal the elements of the TestStruct array, and then use the pointer from the first one to begin the simulation. Thank you, this should achieve what I was looking for. I'm not too good with unmanaged stuff at the moment.